# Set isolation level in Yii globally

Tags: php, yii, isolation-level

I have initial configuration array for `Yii` with database connection element:

```
  'components'=>array(
        ......
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        ),
    )
```

Is it possible to configure in the same way transaction isolation level globally for entire application?

Comment: For database locking?

Comment: @eskimo You can read about transaction isolation level here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: And also here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#performing-transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
'initSQLs' => array('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;'),
```

to 'db'=>array.

You can change SERIALIZABLE to any transaction isolation level needed.